# Using Merge into with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I'm trying to make a stored procedure, who shall update a certain table, work with a list of ints. The same logic was being used for single updates, but for this one table, multiple rows need to be update.

However, I'm getting this error:
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Is there any way to make this merge works with multiple rows? Or do I need to change the logic completely?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_ClientBalanceDetails_ExecuteComplex_RefreshFromClawbacks]      
    @ID AS dbo.IntList READONLY,
    @WorkflowInstanceID int null,
    @AdjustmentFileID int null, 
    @PeriodID int null

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

--AGENTS
MERGE INTO ClientBalanceDetails AS TARGET
USING (
    SELECT
        Clawbacks.ID,
        Clawbacks.ClientBalanceID,
        Clawbacks.AgentClientBalanceDetailID,       
        Clawbacks.ValueDate,
        Clawbacks.ClientID,
        Clawbacks.Amount,
        Clawbacks.Reason,
        Clawbacks.ConfirmationStatus,
        Clawbacks.UnderProrationReview,
        Clawbacks.CreatedBy,
        Clawbacks.CreatedDate,
        Clawbacks.UpdatedBy,
        Clawbacks.UpdatedDate,
        Clawbacks.DeletedBy,
        Clawbacks.DeletedDate,
        Clawbacks.PostBillingDisputeID,
        T05_Periods.FirstDay FirstDay           

    FROM 
        Clawbacks WITH (NOLOCK)             
        INNER JOIN ClientBalances WITH (NOLOCK) ON Clawbacks.ClientBalanceID = ClientBalances.ID                             
        INNER JOIN T05_Periods WITH (NOLOCK) ON ClientBalances.PeriodID = T05_Periods.ID        

    WHERE                   
        ClientBalances.DeletedDate IS NULL
        AND (@WorkflowInstanceID IS NULL OR Clawbacks.WorkflowInstanceID = @WorkflowInstanceID)
        AND (@AdjustmentFileID IS NULL OR Clawbacks.AdjustmentFileID = @AdjustmentFileID)
        AND (@PeriodID IS NULL OR T05_Periods.ID = @PeriodID)
        AND (Clawbacks.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @ID))
        AND (Clawbacks.ConfirmationStatus IN (@ConfirmedStatus, @UnConfirmedStatus, @RejectedStatus) )
        AND (Clawbacks.UnderProrationReview IS NULL OR Clawbacks.UnderProrationReview = 0)              

) AS SOURCE
--Insert new compensations
ON SOURCE.AgentClientBalanceDetailID = TARGET.ID
```

Comment: I would caution using `NOLOCK` here since you could get dirty reads, and thus dirty inserts

Comment: I would also caution against using `MERGE` at all, especially if the pattern is just to update. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: And what would you recommend than?

Comment: Well for updating rows the most direct approach would be to use an update statement.

Comment: Why not simply use another inner join to your table valued parameter instead of using IN?

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement is returning multiple records with the same SOURCE.AgentClientBalanceDetailID. If the source records are duplicates, adding the DISTINCT keyword would fix the issue.

If records with the same AgentClientBalanceDetailID vary by even a single column, your logic is flawed and the database is not going to allow the merge. They do this because SQL must always be consistent regardless of the order of the records. Having varying column values for the same key (AgentClientBalanceDetailID) means that you would get different update results depending upon the order of the records in the select result set.